Python unable to locate the user defined package after installation
I'm doing a PoC on Python package creation. I have followed the steps mentioned in the link.
Please find below the sample project structure
demopackage
  |--__init__.py
  |--config
  |   |--__init__.py
  |   |--dumyconfig.py
  |--processor
  |   |--__init__.py
  |   |--dbprocessor
  |   |    |--__init__.py
  |   |    |--db.py
  |   |--fileprocessor
  |   |    |--__init__.py
  |   |    |--csv.py
  |--validation
  |   |--__init__.py
  |   |--dumyvalidation.py
  |--util
  |   |--__init__.py
  |   |--dumyutil.py
  |--main.py
  |
setup.py

The code is working as expected when I'm running locally. However, after creating the package tar.gz file and installing it in another location I'm getting ModuleNotFound/ImportError for all the internal modules even though they are available inside the site-pacakge folder.
Can someone please help how to resolve this issue?

Do you get the error when python executes find_packages()?

@Andrew'sQuest No, there was no error when I ran Python setup.py sdist...It created the tar.gz file and egg-info folder successfully. Also, there was no error while installing the tar.gz file in a different location. Packages are available as per the structure in the new location.

You've shown a directory layout for your source respository. What is the actually directory structure once the code is installed? (Is demopackage a top-level module found in a directory on your search path, or is each of config, processor, etc a top-level module?)

so the issue comes out when main.py tries to import the packages?

After installation when i run import demopackage, it executes without any error. However, when I'm trying to run from demopackage import main/ config then getting ModuleNotFound error.

@chepner demopackge is the top-level module. The structure is the same after installation in new virtual environment.

So you need to import demopackage.config after installation. import config only works because your script is treating demopackage as a directory on sys.path in which to find modules, not as a package itself.

from demopackage import ... doesn't look for modules in a directory named demopackage; it tries to import a package named demopackage (and some specific submodule in that package) from a directory on your search path, and demopackage is the directory on your search path, not a package in such a directory.

main.py currently uses
from demopackage import config

When your code is installed, demopackage is found in a directory on your search path (sys.path). Before you install the code, though, python main.py adds demopackage itself to the search path, which your script cannot find a package named demopackage, only modules in the directory ../demopackage.
One quick fix would be to add .. to your search path:
PYTHONPATH=.. python main.py

I would, however, recommend not storing main.py (a script) in the package. Change your layout to something like
demopackage
  |--__init__.py
  |--config
  |   |--__init__.py
  |   |--dumyconfig.py
  |--processor
  |   |--__init__.py
  |   |--dbprocessor
  |   |    |--__init__.py
  |   |    |--db.py
  |   |--fileprocessor
  |   |    |--__init__.py
  |   |    |--csv.py
  |--validation
  |   |--__init__.py
  |   |--dumyvalidation.py
  |--util
      |--__init__.py
      |--dumyutil.py
setup.py
main.py

so that demopackage is in the directory that's implicitly added to your path when you execute python main.py.
